# Adding WYSIWYG to a site that is not your own?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, ckeditor

This website that I use has a WYSIWYG that ONLY works in IE. And I refuse to use IE or to tell my non-tech team to use IE.

I was wondering if there is a user script or browser plugin that would enable anyone to inject a WYSIWYG such as CKeditor.com onto any site textarea?

Edit: I would also be willing to work on it myself if anyone wants to help or give advice. We could then post it on userscripts or something ...

Comment: IE is infact one of the worst performing browsers. I would totally recommend getting a multi browser compatitable WYSIWYG like tinymce http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Comment: I told them to change it, but I don't know when they'll do it, if ever ... And I can't wait for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension in Firefox as long as you get at least a textarea in that CMS: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6147/

Comment: Ahhh yes! From the description, it looks like it's exactly what I am looking for! Unfortunately, I upgraded to Firefox 4 beta last night, so I have to find a work around for this. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have access to the code, anything you do will be a hack.

With that in mind, I would start looking at [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/). It is a firefox plugin that allows you to inject javascript code into any web page on your machine. Its a long road, but that's probably your first step.

One word of warning however: While I share in your dislike of IE, it sounds like your hatred has grown to the point where it is being counterproductive. Seriously consider whether what you are about to do is worth the effort.

Comment: The issue with IE is that's it's not for me, it's for a customer rep team. I can't ask them to switch browsers back and forth ...

Answer (score 1):

Would a Firefox [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419/) that displays websites as if they were in IE do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

I like [Stargazer712's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189961/adding-wysiwyg-to-a-site-that-is-not-your-own/3190059#3190059) (look into Greasemonkey), but there is another option.

**Suck it up and use IE for just this site.**

Hey, I hate IE6 and 7 as much as the next Web developer.  I advise non-techies to stay away from it, and to use Firefox or Chrome.  My answer isn't meant to be flip or funny.

Sometimes, if you need to get the job done, you choose the best tool for the job (even if you don't like *using* the tool) to get the work done in the most efficient manner possible.  In this case, it sounds like using IE to access this particular Web site takes care of the problem without a single line of code or documentation written on your part.

**The alternative is spending hours finding (and *testing* -- because you won't be the only user) an alternative...or worse, spending hours or *days* developing (and, again, *testing*) your own code to fix the problem that, at the end of the day, is really only caused by your strong dislike of the one  software application that works.**

Comment: The issue is that's it's not for me, it's for a customer rep team. I can't ask them to switch browsers back and forth ...

Comment: Playing Devil's Advocate here...why can't you?